# Binomial coefficients and $p$-adic limits

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, ceiling-and-floor-functions, p-adic-number-theory

I was reading Schoof's Catalan's Conjecture, and on page 37, while proving *Cassels' Theorem* it is mentioned that by Exercise 5.7, the denominators of the binomial coefficients $\binom{\frac{p}{q}}{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq \lfloor \frac{p}{q} \rfloor + 1$, where $p$ and $q$ are odd prime numbers, are powers of $q$.

I found a [proof](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/binomialcoeffpadic.pdf) by Keith Conrad, but it uses $p$-adic limits, so I decided to read through Gouvea's *$p$-adic Numbers: An Introduction*.

I still don't know what is going on, any insight please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof you cited does not really use $p$-adic numbers but just the $p$-adic topology on $\mathbf Q$ and continuity of polynomial functions in the $p$-adic topology.

Suppose $F$ is a field and $|\cdot|$ is an absolute value on $F$. Let $f \colon F \to F$ be a continuous function and $S \subset F$ be a subset such that $|f(s)| \leq 1$ for all $s \in S$. If $x \in F$ is a *limit* of points in $A$, say $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$.  By continuity, $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(s_n)$.  The absolute value on $F$ is continuous, so $|f(x)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |f(s_n)|$. Since $|f(s_n)| \leq 1$ for all $n$, we get $|f(x)| \leq 1$.

Now apply this to $F = \mathbf Q$, $|\cdot| = |\cdot|_p$ ($p$-adic absolute value), and $f(x) = \binom{x}{k}$, and $S = \mathbf Z$.  Polynomials are continuous functions since addition and multiplication are continuous.  A rational number whose denominator is *not* divisible by $p$ is a $p$-adic limit of integers: if $a/b$ is a fraction where $p \nmid b$, then for each positive integer $n$ we can solve $bs_n \equiv a \bmod p^n$ for some integer $s_n$, which means $|bs_n - a|_p \leq 1/p^n$, so $|s_n - a/b|_p = |(bs_n-a)|_p/|b|_p = |bs_n-a|_p \leq 1/p^n$.  Thus $s_n \to a/b$ as $n \to \infty$.
Therefore $|\binom{a/b}{k}|_p \leq 1$ since $|\binom{s_n}{k}|_k \leq 1$ for all $n$. That shows the fraction $\binom{a/b}{k}$ has no $p$ in its denominator when $p \nmid b$.

Comment: thanks, it's still taking me time to wrap my head around it, but this helps :)

Comment: Is there a reference source for this proposition?

Comment: @AgentSmith which "proposition"?  There are numerous things stated in the answer and I don't know which one you're asking about.

Comment: @KCd The proposition that the denominators of the binomial coefficients $\binom{\frac{p}{q}}{k}$, where $p$ and $q$ are odd prime numbers, are powers of $q$. I am aware that there are more general versions of this statement.

Comment: @AgentSmith  when $\ell$ is a prime other than $q$, $p/q$ is an $\ell$-adic integer, so it's an $\ell$-adic limit of integers $n_i$. Thus $\binom{p/q}{k}$ is an $\ell$-adic limit of the integers $\binom{n_i}{k}$, which makes $\binom{p/q}{k}$ an $\ell$-adic integer, so this fraction has no $\ell$ in its denominator. Letting $\ell$ run over all primes other than $q$, the only possible prime factor in the denominator is $q$, so the denominator is a power of $q$.

Answer (score 1):

This was really a bit too long to put into a comment to KCd's answer, but I thought it might help to see a specific concrete example of such a limit.

We already know that $\binom{m}{n}$ is an integer when $m$ is an integer, so we could write down a specific limit of integers that approaches $\frac{a}{b}$ in the p-adic topology when $b$ and $p$ are relatively prime, because

$$p^{\varphi(b)k}(b-a) + a \equiv 0 \mod b$$
$$1*(b-a) + a \equiv 0 \mod b$$
$$b \equiv 0 \mod b$$

This means $\frac{p^{\varphi(b)k}(b-a) + a}{b}$ is an integer. Then we know that because $p^{\varphi(b)k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ this means we have our sequence of integers approaching $\frac{a}{b}$,

$$\frac{p^{\varphi(b)k}(b-a) + a}{b} \to \frac{a}{b}$$.

This means our limit of integers is

$$\binom{\frac{a}{b}}{n} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \binom{\frac{p^{\varphi(b)k}(b-a) + a}{b}}{n}$$

And we have that

$$\left|\binom{\frac{a}{b}}{n}\right|_p = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\binom{\frac{p^{\varphi(b)k}(b-a) + a}{b}}{n}\right|_p \le 1$$

Comment: thanks so much!